# coffeescript passing require() parameters wrong

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, coffeescript, require

Code `require ('./routes') app` compiles to `require('./routes'(app));` But I need it to compile to `require('./routes)(app)`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses serve two purposes in CoffeeScript:

1. They group expressions: `(a + b) * c`
2. They're used to call functions: `f(x)`.

When you say this:

```
f (x)
```

there is some ambiguity about what the parentheses around `x` mean; are they grouping parentheses or function calling parentheses? CoffeeScript chooses the former as you've seen.

If you want (or need) to use parentheses for calling a function, you don't want a space before the opening parenthesis, you want:

```
f(x)
```

In your case you'd want:

```
require('./routes') app
```

or even:

```
require('./routes')(app)
(require './routes') app
```

Comment: Here is another way to write it: `(require './routes') app`

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: Yeah, that one too. I tend to forget that version because it looks too much like Lisp.